# Getting values from related tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, activerecord, yii2

I'm trying to find a route in which there are 2 cities. I have tables "route", "city" and "route_city". On input i have two city ids(from and to).
My tables:

city

```
id name
1  Kiev
2  Rome
```

route

```
id name
1  Kiev-Rome
2  Rome-Kiev
```

route_city

```
id route_id city_id sort
1         1        1   1
2         1        2   2
3         2        2   1
4         2        1   2
```

I tried:

```
SELECT `route_id` FROM `route_city` WHERE (`route_city`.`city_id` IN ('1', '2')) GROUP BY `route_city`.`route_id`
```

If i have from=Kiev and to=Rome, i get both routes.

1)How i can get only one route?

2)And how i can create this query in Yii2 Framework with ActiveRecord?

Comment: don't know about Yii2 Framework but you can use LIMIT in sql query: SELECT `route_id` FROM `route_city` WHERE (`route_city`.`city_id` IN ('1', '2')) GROUP BY `route_city`.`route_id` LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cant find `route` with this table structure. Need to get it from another table or change structure.

Answer (score 0):

is the `sort` column your code for `from` and `to`? Like this: if sort=1, it's `from` and if sort=2, it's `to`?

If yes, to do from=Kiev and to=Rome you can do :

```
SELECT `route_id` FROM `route_city` WHERE (`route_city`.`city_id` IN ('1', '2')) AND `route_city`.`sort`=1 GROUP BY `route_city`.`route_id`
```

For Yii I can't be of any help !

Comment: `sort` column set position city in route. It's can be like: Kiev-Krakow-Rome with sort 1-2-3. And if select where `from`=Krakow and `to`=Rome i can't add to query `where sort=1`. `sort` in `from` must be less than `sort` in `to`, but i don't know how add this to the query.